# How to remove duplicate lists from a list of lists in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists in Python where the inner lists all have 6 elements each:

```
k = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6], [5, 6, 2, 2, 3, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5], [3, 3, 6, 4, 7, 7], [4, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6], ...]
```

The only condition that is required is that the 6th element of each sub-list can be identical to any other element; however, all of the first 5 elements of each sub-list must be unique.

The result of above list should be:

```
k = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5], ...]
```

As you can see I do care about preserving the order of number in the inner lists.

There is a similar question in here but it does not address the constraint I have in my specific problem. ([How to Remove Duplicate Lists from a List in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64667628/how-to-remove-duplicate-lists-from-a-list-in-python))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the list with a list comprehension and test that the set made up of the first 5 elements has length 5.

For example

```
keep = [x for x in k if len(set(x[:-1]))==5]
# or 
keep = [x for x in k if len(set(x[0:5]))==5]
```